# Access to pointers two levels down in Parse in c#

Tags: c#, pointers, parse-platform, parse-dotnet-sdk

I've stored data in Parse and now I have to access it to create a topTen score for users playing the game allowing a user to only to be shown on the list ones.
The data is stored such that each game has a run has a session which has a user with name, pass etc.

So it goes Run Session => User (name, pass, email, etc).

I need to access the name for a user in order to check whether the user is already present on the topTen as well as show the name.

While I can get access to the data on Session I can't reach the data on User.

```
        int counter = 0;

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Runs").WhereEqualTo("scoreIdentifier", GameController.instance.scoreContext).OrderByDescending("score");
    query.Include("session.user");
    query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
        IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;
        foreach (var item in results) {
            if (item.ContainsKey("score")) {
                if (counter < 10) {
                    topTenScores[counter] = item.Get<int>("score");
                    topTenNames[counter] = item.ObjectId;
                    ParseObject session = item.Get<ParseObject>("session");
                    Task<ParseObject> user = session.FetchAsync<ParseObject>();

                    user.ContinueWith(tt => {
                        ParseObject userName = tt.Result;
                        Debug.Log("CHECK FOR TT " + tt.Result.ObjectId);
                    });
                }
                if (counter == 9) {
                    updateTopTen = true;
                }
                counter++;
            }
            if (counter < 10)
                updateTopTen = true;
        }
    });
```

tt.Result.ObjectId writes out the objectId for Session whereas I would think it would be for User.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own - the fetchAync() needed a few more iterations:

```
public void TopTenHighScore() {
    int sessionCounter = 0;

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Runs").WhereEqualTo("scoreIdentifier", GameController.instance.scoreContext).OrderByDescending("score");
    query.Include("session.user");
    query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
        IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;
        foreach (var item in results) {
            if (item.ContainsKey("score")) {
                if (sessionCounter < 10) {
                    // --- this is for the overall Score
                    topTenScores[sessionCounter] = item.Get<int>("score"); 

                    ParseObject sessionPointer = item.Get<ParseObject>("session");
                    Task<ParseObject> session = sessionPointer.FetchAsync<ParseObject>();  

                    session.ContinueWith(tt => {
                        ParseObject userPointer = tt.Result;                            
                       Task<ParseObject> user = userPointer.Get<ParseObject>("user").FetchAsync<ParseObject>();

                       user.ContinueWith(ttt => {
                           ParseObject userFinal = ttt.Result;
                           userNamesList.Add(userFinal.Get<string>("displayName"));
                       });
                    });
                }
                if (sessionCounter == 9) {
                    sessionCounterDone = true;
                }
                sessionCounter++;
            }
            // if the amount of sessions played in total is not above 10
            if (sessionCounter < 10)
                sessionCounterDone = true;
        }
    });
}
```